# Shared nuget.config file on TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have this setup:

```
$/Shared/nuget.config
$/Shared/.nuget
$/SomeTeamProject/nuget.config
$/SomeTeamProject/SomeTeamProject.sln
```

*Using VS.Net 2015 Update 3*

**nuget.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>  
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="$\..\..\Shared\.nuget" />
  </config>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="automatic" value="true"/>
  </packageRestore>
</configuration>
```

I'd like to refer to the `nuget.config` file from `Shared`. 
(I tried adding `nuget.config` to `$/` but that's not allowed by TFS) 
Added `$/Shared/nuget.config` as an existing item to `SomeTeamProject` 
but it doesn't seem to work.. 
 It only works when I **copy** `nuget.config` from `Shared` to the `SomeTeamProject` folder.

It seems to ignore the referenced `nuget.config` file and creates a `.packages` folder in the `SomeTeamProject` folder..

A hard copy of `nuget.config` from the `Shared` Team Project works ok.

[image: Hard Copy]

But a linked (add existing file) is not being used by NuGet for this solution:

[image: Link]

[image: Solution files]

[image: Shared Team Project files]

Comment: Do the Shared and SomeTeamProject are projects and the nuget.config file in different projects? Please share a screenshot about your solution construction to help us understanding the issue. And if a .packages folder is created in SomeTeamProject folder and a packages.config file added into your project, it means the package restore has successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nuget.config file isn't used when you place it in "Shared" folder. You can refer to [Configuring NuGet Behavior](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) and specially [Priority ordering](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#priority-ordering) section to see how the nuget.config file works.

And there is no way to simply add a link to get it work. The nuget only check the files in current folder or up level folder, it does not check the linked nuget.config file.

Comment: I tried putting nuget.config in $/ before but TFS wouldn't let me. That's why I created the Shared team project. I'll check out the links you provided.

Comment: @grmbl So you created another team project "Shared" to place the nuget.config file?

Comment: Yes, the file is now under source control but cannot be used as a referenced nuget.config (add as existing item in another solution) so we have to get this Shared project and when we create a new project copy that nuget.config file over. It works but I'd prefer to add a link to it but that's the problem.

Comment: @grmbl Sorry for didn't see that you are using TFS repository. I'm afraid there is no way to simply add a link to get it work. The nuget only check the files in current folder or up level folder, it does not check the linked nuget.config file.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion:)

Comment: You should put your last comment as answer including the links as reference.